# I am having trouble creating and updating a dictionary by using the below code

Tags: dictionary, odoo, qweb, odoo-13

For creating a dict, i used the following code:

```
<t t-set="count" t-value="dict()"/>

<t t-foreach="count_obj" t-as="ob">

<t t-set="count" t-esc="count.update({ob.id: ob.name})"/>

</t>
```

But i am getting  a none value.Why?
Can anyone help me?Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

shahinsha ummer

You have to specify the value in `dict` form when you try setting the **value**
[`<t t-set="variable" t-value=""/>`].

In your example, there is no need to set the `variable` before the **loop** with `dictionary` form it will do **nothing**.

```
<t t-foreach="count_obj" t-as="ob">
    <t t-set="count" t-value="{ob.id: ob.name}"/> <!-- Set the Value in form of dictionar -->
    <span t-esc="count"/>
</t>
```